# Prove that $\text{Cov}(aX + bY, Z) = a\text{Cov}(X, Z) + b\text{Cov}(Y, Z)$.

Tags: covariance, least-squares

So far, I have:
$$\mathbb{E}[(aX+bY-\mathbb{E}(aX+bY))(Z-\mathbb{E}(Z))] = 
\mathbb{E}[Z(aX + bY)-Z\mathbb{E}(aX +bY) - \mathbb{E}(Z)(aX + bY)-\mathbb{E}(Z)E(aX + bY)] = 
\mathbb{E}(Z(aX + bY - \mathbb{E}(aX + bY)) - \mathbb{E}(Z)(aX + bY - \mathbb{E}(aX + bY))$$

I don't really know what to do next.

Comment: Hint: $\mathbb{E}(aX + bY))$ is a constant and it can be puulled out of tte expectation.

Answer (score 0):

Can you use this formula instead?
$$ \text{Cov}(X,Y) =\mathbb{E}(XY)-\mathbb{E}(X)\mathbb{E}(Y).$$

Thus
\begin{align*}
\text{Cov}(aX + bY,Z) &=\mathbb{E}[(aX + bY)Z]-\mathbb{E}(aX + bY)\mathbb{E}(Z)\\
&=\mathbb{E}(aXZ + bYZ) - [a \mathbb{E}(X) + b \mathbb{E}(Y)]\mathbb{E}(Z)\\
&=...
\end{align*}
Can you proceed from here?